# scipy splrep() with weights not fitting the given curve

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, bspline

Using scipy's [splrep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) I can easily fit a test sinewave:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")

# Generate test sinewave
x = np.arange(0, 20, .1)
y = np.sin(x)

# Interpolate
tck = splrep(x, y)
x_spl = x + 0.05 # Just to show it wors
y_spl = splev(x_spl, tck)
plt.plot(x_spl, y_spl)
```

[image: Spline sinewave plot]

The [splrep documentation states](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) that the default value for the weight parameter is `np.ones(len(x))`. However, plotting this results in a totally different plot:

```
tck = splrep(x, y, w=np.ones(len(x_spl)))
y_spl = splev(x_spl, tck)
plt.plot(x_spl, y_spl)
```

[image: Plot with splev and weights]

The documentation also states that the smoothing condition `s` is different when a weight array is given - but even when setting `s=len(x_spl) - np.sqrt(2*len(x_spl))` (the default value without a weight array) the result does not strictly correspond to the original curve as shown in the plot.

What do I need to change in the code listed above in order to make the interpolation with weight array (as listed above) output the same result as the interpolation without the weights?
I have tested this with scipy 0.17.0. [Gist with a test IPython notebook](https://gist.github.com/ulikoehler/6198f9f154a36e06f2c1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to change one line of your code to get the identical output:

```
tck = splrep(x, y, w=np.ones(len(x_spl)))
```

should become

```
tck = splrep(x, y, w=np.ones(len(x_spl)), s=0)
```

So, the only difference is that you have to specify `s` instead of using the default one.

When you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py#L318) of `splrep` you will see why that is necessary:

```
if w is None:
    w = ones(m, float)
    if s is None:
        s = 0.0

else:
    w = atleast_1d(w)
    if s is None:
        s = m - sqrt(2*m)
```

which means that, if neither weights nor `s` are provided, `s` is set to 0 and if you provide weights but no `s` then `s = m - sqrt(2*m)` where `m = len(x)`.

So, in your example above you compare outputs with the same weights but with different `s` (which are `0` and `m - sqrt(2*m)`, respectively).